# SSIS convert string to date

Tags: ssis, expression

I am new to SSIS, have been  trying to convert the string to date.
My input column string  is in the format of MM.DD.yy 10.11.16 
My requirement is to convert 2016-10-11  yyyy-mm-dd

Below is the expression I tried but its loading as null in the destination.

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,1,2) + "-" + 
SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,7,2))
```

---

Comment: The expression you have correctly returns a `DATETIME` value. Is your destination column / variable that needs to be transformed to `yyyy-mm-dd` a string data type?

Comment: What data type is the target column? What do you see if you add a data viewer in your package?

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

in the DataFlowTask add a script component between Source and Destination

Check The `FILE_DATE` as Input And Create A column `outFILE_DATE` (Type: DT_DATE) as Output

in the Script Window add the Following Code

```
Row.outFILEDATE = DATETIME.ParseExact(Row.FILEDATE,"MM.DD.yy",New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("En-GB"))
```

And Map the `outFILE_DATE`  to the Destination Column

**Second Method**

Use this expression :

```
(DT_DATE)("20" + SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,7,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(FILE_DATE,1,2) )
```

it works only when Year is >= 2000

Answer (score 0):

In a number of cases Date field is coming from Excel or CSV files - do not use any Data Conversion object convertion for date - just convert it in File Source